# ASP.NET TreeView auto expand?

Tags: asp.net, controls, treeview

Does anyone know how to show a asp:TreeView always expanded to the leaves?  So if I have a 2-level tree, I want it to be expanded at all times.  Is there a property on TreeView that does this or could you show the code snippet on how to do this?

Thank you very much!
Ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```

if you also want to disable expand-collapse symbols in the tree:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowExpandCollapse="false">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can use an Integer if you only want to show the roots item per defualt:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView1.ExpandDepth = 1;
    }
```